# jquery while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the distance for each ad (thumbnails). I am working with the Google Maps JavaScript API. The problem is that only the first ad has a distance displayed, or, if I change the code, every distances are displayed in each thumbnails.

How do you display the distance from Google (or jQuery) when the thumbnails are in a while loop? Your help is gladly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

  include 'includes/db.inc.php'; //Connection to the database.
  include 'includes/login.inc.php'; //Processes the login and the sign up info to fetch the user info in the database.

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Vous avez besoin d'un service économique? Trouvez-le sur Jobbinn.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="petites annonces classées, kijiji, Les PACs">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/jobbinn_logo.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <title>Jobbinn</title>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom CSS file -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- stylesheet for index.php (style folder) -->
    <link href="style/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Roboto Condensed Font -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  </head>
  <body>

    <?php

      if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['password']) == true) {

        $sel_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]' AND password = '$_SESSION[password]'";

        if($run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_sql)) {

          if(mysqli_num_rows($run_sql) == 1) {

            include 'includes/dash_header.inc.php';

          }

        }

      } 

    ?>
    <?php include 'includes/header.inc.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'includes/subheader.inc.php'; ?>

    <div id="head">
      <div class="container bring-down">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Vous avez besoin d'un service économique? </br> Trouvez-le sur Jobbinn.</h2>
            <h4>Trouvez. Achetez. Profitez de la vie.</h4>
            <form class="form-group" action="search.php">
              <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Que recherchez-vous?">
              <button name="search_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Trouver un service</button>
              <a id="start" href="startselling.php" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Commencer à vendre</a>
            </form>
            <div class="icon-align-right">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.jobbinn.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x icon-spacing" style="color:#F1F1EC;"></i></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=Quand%20vous%20voulez%20un%20travail%20bien%20fait%20sans%20que%20%C3%A7a%20vous%20co%C3%BBte%20un%20bras.%20http%3A//www.jobbinn.com%20%23mtl"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x icon-spacing" style="color:#F1F1EC;"></i></a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/instajobbinn"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x icon-spacing" style="color:#F1F1EC;"></i></a>
              <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A//www.jobbinn.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x icon-spacing" style="color:#F1F1EC;"></i></a>
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A//www.jobbinn.com&title=Quand%20vous%20voulez%20un%20travail%20bien%20fait,%20sans%20payer%20un%20bras.&summary=&source="><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x icon-spacing" style="color:#F1F1EC;"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="thumbnails">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Services Populaires</h2>
        <h4 style="color:#333;">Choisissez parmi nos services les plus populaires.</h4>
        <div class="row">

          <?php 

            $return_arr = array();
            $sel_sql = "SELECT
                        a_id AS annonce_id,
                        titre AS annonce_titre,
                        image AS annonce_image,
                        price AS annonce_prix,
                        postal_code AS annonce_code,
                        city AS annonce_ville,
                        numcommentaires AS num_commentaires,
                        SUM(communication)+SUM(service)+SUM(recommandation) AS total_rating
                        FROM annonces a
                        INNER JOIN users u
                        ON a.user_id = u.id
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                          b.ad_id,
                          SUM(communication) AS communication,
                          SUM(service) AS service,
                          SUM(recommandation) AS recommandation,
                          COUNT(id) AS numcommentaires
                          FROM commentaires b
                          GROUP BY b.ad_id) b
                        ON a.a_id = b.ad_id
                        WHERE statut = 'published'
                        GROUP BY a_id
                        LIMIT 20
                       ";

            $conn->set_charset("utf8");
            $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_sql);
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {

              $return_arr[] = $rows['annonce_code'];

              echo '

              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <a href="annonce.php?post_id='.$rows['annonce_id'].'">
                    <input class="tid" type="hidden" name="annonceid" value="'.$rows['annonce_id'].'">
                    <input class="tid" type="hidden" name="annoncecode" value="'.$rows['annonce_code'].'">
                    <p>'.$rows['annonce_titre'].'</p>
                    <img src="'.$rows['annonce_image'].'" alt="image">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <div>
                        <h3 style="color:#05C33C; font-weight:bold;">'.$rows['annonce_prix'].'$</h3>
                        <p style="color:#FE6E32;">'.($rows['num_commentaires'] == '' ? 'nouveau' : ''.substr($rows['total_rating'] / $rows['num_commentaires'] / 3,0,3).'/10 ('.$rows['num_commentaires'].')').'</p>
                        <p>'.$rows['annonce_ville'].'</p>
                        <p class="distance-'.$rows['annonce_id'].'"></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>

              ';

            }

            $postal = json_encode($return_arr);

          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-container" class="container profile text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <img src="images/icon_graph.png" class="img-circle">
          <h3>Faites avancer les choses</h3>
          <p>Des gens qui aiment se qu'ils font vous aident à tout faire à un prix imbattable.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <img src="images/icon_money.png" class="img-circle">
          <h3>Offrez vos services</h3>
          <p>Qu'est-ce que vous faites de mieux? Créez votre annonce et commencez à vendre. C'est gratuit et ça prend seulement 5 minutes.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <img src="images/icon_gears.png" class="img-circle">
          <h3>Confiance et sécurité</h3>
          <p>Votre sécurité est notre top priorité. Des transactions sécuritaires et notre équipe vous protègent en tout temps.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <?php include 'includes/footer.inc.php'; ?>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $.each($(".thumbnail"), function() {

        $this = $(this);
        id = $this.find('input[name="annonceid"]').val();
        code = $this.find('input[name="annoncecode"]').val();
        //$this.find('input[name="annonceid"]').val(text);
        $(".distance-" + id).text(code + "/" + id);

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); //Creates a new request to the API
          service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: ['"' + code + '"'], //The seller side
          destinations: ["J7Z 7B9"], //The buyer side
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,//Can have multiple travel mode like driving, cycling and walking
        }, callback);

        function callback(response, status) { //We get a document in JSON format
          if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

                var element = results[j];
                var distance = element.distance.text; //The distance between the origin and a destination
                var duration = element.duration.text; //The time it takes to get there
                var from = origins[i];
                var to = destinations[j];

                console.log(element);
                console.log(distance);
                console.log(duration);
                console.log(from);
                console.log(to);

              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code under var to = destination[j] was just a test.

Comment: you can increase the chance to get a good answer with providing a full working piece of code without any dependencies

Comment: You want to see the whole code?

Comment: people try to answer this anyway, even they cannot test your code, so never mind....

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute in HTML must be unique as per the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). jQuery will therefore assume there is only one element when you manipulate `#distance`. This leaves you with the behavior that you see in which only the first element has the desired result.

To solve this, you could simply put the row id as part of the id as such: `#distance-1`, `#distance-2`, etc.

Comment: Or better, a class specifically for the purpose.

Comment: Then it should be $("#distance" + rowid) if I understand correctly? I guess I will have to echo $rows['annonce_id'] next to id="distance" too. I will give that a try.